# World War MMV - Enigmatic Puzzle

Tags: mathematics, knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, science

[image: World War MMV]

Image transcript:

```
Clues:

    +----+ ' +-------+ +--------+   +-------+ +-------+
    | 2H |   | 36090 | | 146365 | g | 22055 | | 14035 |
    +----+   +-------+ +--------+   +-------+ +-------+

Instructions: Name That Hero
           _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ e _ _ _ _ _
```

Hint:

> The four numbers have something in common.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The hint helps to find that all the numbers are divisible by 5. Looking closer at the title, MMV is Roman numerals for 2005, which again, all the numbers can be divided by.

> Performing the division gives the string 2H ' 18 73 g 11 7.

> Using the tag 'science' as another clue, these numbers are a lookup into the periodic table, giving the string 2H ' Ar Ta g Na N. While 2H is not an element, it is used in chemistry for Deuterium, an isotope of hydrogen. With this final substitution, the decoded string is revealed - "d'Artagnan".

(Credit to Stiv for decoding 2H.)

> A quick Google search of d'Artagnan 2005 gives the movie The Three Musketeers, in which d'Artagnan is played by Volodymyr Zelenskyy - the current president of Ukraine and certainly a hero both in the movie and in reality.

Comment: I'm just going to [drop this here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deuterium) :)